# Animated image as splash screen on android with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen

I have been googling for a while now; to add an animated splash screen in my android/phonegap 
project but most of the posts/blogs refer to use the following code :

```
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 10000);
```

This is working perfectly for plain image files. But when i use an animated images (Currently using *.gif files, know that gif's are not supported in android) for splash screens its not working.

I also found that android's animation and alpha animation api's can be used. Can somebody point me to a nice tutorials.

I just want to show an splash screen with some animation.

Thanks,

Nanashi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge animated gif's are not supported on Android. If you want to do an animated splash screen you will need to do some Java coding. Check out this link:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/113831/An-Advanced-Splash-Screen-for-Android-App

Comment: Hi Simon, I followed the above link and i was able to show the animated splash screen but the problem is after showing splash screen there is a black screen appearing for 2-3 sec and then my main activity starts. Ideally want i want is : show the animated splash screen while my resources are getting loaded. And thanks for the link

Comment: Seems like you need to set a longer time out before the splash screen goes away.

Comment: @SimonMacDonald How could I mixed Java code & Js code in this case?